# How to find interval in days, week or days and month or days?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, stored-procedures, intervals

I have to find the total no. of month, days or month, weeks or weeks, days or only days on the basis of interval between start and end date which user gives to the input.

Like if the interval between two dates is not more than 30 than output should be only in days

For example `- StartDate - 1 July                          EndDate-24 July`

```
Time_Type                  StartDate                          EndDate
   Day                      1 July                            24 July
```

Interval is more than 30 days but less than 90 Days than output should only in days and weeks and my week start from Monday and ends on Sunday

For example `- StartDate - 1 July 2015                         EndDate- 23 September 2015`

```
Time_Type                      StartDate                              EndDate
   Day                          1-07-2015                            5-07-2015
  Week                         Week2(july)                    Week3(September)
   Day                          21-09-2015                        23-09-2015

`Interval is more than 90 Days than` output should be in days and months
```

For example `- StartDate – 22 April 2015                      EndDate - 8 December 2015`

```
Time_Type                    StartDate                                EndDate
   Day                       22-04-2015                          30-04-2015
  Week                        May2015                             November 2015
   Day                       01-12-2015                          08-12-2015
```

Here the weeks can be the no of week by year wise like week2 (July) would be 26 week.

Comment: @JulienVavasseur it is hardly the datediff that makes this question complicated

Comment: once you know the diff in days, use CASE

Comment: @JulienVavasseur sounds like you already have the answer with DATEDIFF and CASE. I would love to see it posted

Comment: how do you define a month ? Will startdate 2015-01-29 enddate 2015-02-28 be a month ? Same question with weeks, wednesday week 1, tuesday week 2 could be 2 weeks, since both weeks are included, 1 week rounded off or 0 weeks since there are not whole weeks

Comment: For month if startdate 2015-01-29 enddate 2015-02-28 yeah it would be a month as February is whole included and 3 days left of January  for weeks we will go to the first monday which is on or after start date then from there to sunday on or before end date...btw in this range we don't need weeks or months

Comment: It would be far simpler if you provided sample data (as it exists in your table or tables) and then, based only on that sample, the expected result.

Comment: the thing is only thing I am getting from user is dates what I want I have already given in question with each scenario...I will just say how many month days or weeks by the query..the input is only dates

Comment: First the sample data file is not needed as we here only need dates and according to dates we just have to break up the dates according to week, day or month day or only in days according to interval.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DATEDIFF(D,StartDate,EndDate)` to find out how many days between two dates.

Then you can use a `CASE WHEN X < 120 THEN 'A' WHEN X < 90 THEN 'B' ELSE 'C' END` to select the formatting style.

And I think this is what you want to do for the formatting

```
SELECT DATENAME(DAY,GETDATE()) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())

SELECT 'Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE()) - DATEPART(WEEK,DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE()) + '/' + DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) + '/' + '1') AS NVARCHAR)+ ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE())
```

But I am not sure what you are doing with `WEEK`? there is no such thing as week 1 of any month as months don't always start on 'Mondays'

What I have done is work out the week of the year (for the date) and subtract the week of the year for the first day of the month (for the date).

You will need to use your date where I have `GETDATE()`. So in your case you so this once with StartDate and again with EndDate.  You may want to turn this formatting code into a function if your going to use it more than once.

I hope you can put this all together, I could do it for you, but I am sure you can get things the way you want with what's in this answer. If not then let me know and I will post more details.

Comment: I have a start date and end date so how to use both in place of getdate()

Comment: You dont use both. You use one at a time.  I will update my answer to help explain.

Comment: yeah ok..that will surely help

Comment: I have made some updates but i have to leave now, If you still don't have an answer by the time i get back then i will be sure to offer a better answer. I suggest you play around with the above ideas and i am sure you  will work it all out.

Comment: yeah ok...but why I don't see the change?

Comment: I haven't been successful in doing that code...if you are available can you please help me also please update your answer I don't see any change in and previous one

Comment: how to add start and end date here?

Answer (score 0):

This will count the whole weeks or months when the timeinterval is above 30 otherwise it will just calculate days:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '2015-07-01'
DECLARE @EndDate   date = '2015-12-24'

SELECT 
  CASE timetype
  WHEN 'days'
  THEN null
  WHEN 'weeks'
  THEN
    datediff(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) - 
    datediff(week, dateadd(d, datediff(d, 1, @StartDate) / 7 * 7, 7), 
    dateadd(d, datediff(d, -1, @EndDate) / 7 * 7, 0)) * 7
  WHEN 'months'
  THEN
    datediff(d, @StartDate, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, @StartDate)+ 1, 0)) +
    datediff(d, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, @EndDate), 0), @EndDate) + 1
  END as remainingdays,
  CASE timetype 
  WHEN 'days'
  THEN datediff(d, @StartDate, @EndDate)
  WHEN 'weeks'
  THEN weeks
  WHEN 'months'
  THEN
    datediff(m, dateadd(d, -1, @StartDate), dateadd(d, 1, @EndDate)) - 1
  END as diff,
  timetype
  FROM 
    (SELECT CASE WHEN datediff(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) between 0 and 30 THEN 'days'
         WHEN datediff(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) < 90 THEN 'weeks'
         WHEN datediff(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) >= 90 THEN 'months' END timetype,
         datediff(week, dateadd(d, datediff(d, 1, @StartDate) / 7 * 7, 7), 
         dateadd(d, datediff(d, -1, @EndDate) / 7 * 7, 0)) weeks
     ) x
```

Comment: but for your dates it will be only giving month 5 nothing for the left days :(

Comment: sorry but please look at my output...I need a start and end date for each of the dimension of day or if it month...also you code is giving output in same row for month and day..I have already posted my output please make it in that way

Comment: Are you seriously complaining that the result set is in 1 row instead of 3 rows ? I gave you all the code to calculate everything at a really high level complexity. Leaving the rest of this challange to you.

Comment: Ok  lets just leave that but main thing is I want start date and end date I have already put that in the ouput of my question this thing I have already worked out how to get remaining day but I want the exact date instead. Thats what I need

Comment: man thank you for your help but I want another output and that is much different that your code provided...I m still trying to figurre my way out.